# php - one time access by looking up serial in a .dat file

Tags: php

i've now written this short script.

It records a serial or token number, checks to see if its in a .dat file, and allows access if its present. Otherwise it denies access to the site. 
It also removes the token from the file once it has been redeemed as it were.

However, when i add multiple tokes in the dat file, the code doesn work properly. It only works with a single  entry. How would i make it work for multiple entries.

im thinking of maybe implementing some sort of array somewhere? or explode?

**index.php**

```
require_once "married.php";

session_start();

$url_request = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . 
    "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$token = substr($url_request,45);

$_SESSION["cookie"] = $token;
$tk = $_SESSION["cookie"];
$ips = array();
$page = file("urls.dat");
foreach($page as $line)
{   
    array_push($ips, $line);    
}
if(in_array($tk, $ips))
{
    //header("Location: mysite.co.uk");
    echo "<title>My Site</title>Here is my site";
    $file = fopen("ip_match.dat","a");
    fwrite($file,$tk . " " . $ip . "\r\n");
    fclose($file);

    $oldMessage = $_SESSION["cookie"];
    $deletedFormat = "";
    $str=file_get_contents('urls.dat');
    $str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);
    file_put_contents('urls.dat', $str);
    exit;

} else {
    echo ("<title>404 Not Found</title>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>The requested URL was not found on this server.
        <br>
        <br>
        Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use             an ErrorDocument to handle the request. test");
    exit;
}
```

**urls.dat**
    1089yht

**url**: http://mmmmmmmmmmmmm.co.uk/url/index.php?key=1089yht

ps. Happy Holidays all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at **JSON**. You could do something like this:

```
$tokens = ['foo', 'bar'];
file_put_contents('urls.json', json_encode($tokens));

// and then you can decode it back
// returns ['foo', 'bar']
$decodedTokens = json_decode(file_get_contents('urls.json'));
```

If you still want to use simple text file, you could save every record at new line and then load line by line.

```
$tokens = [];
while(! feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);

    // or save to array
    $tokens[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: and how would i remove token from the file using json

Comment: Just remove it from array and save it again.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$str = preg_replace("/{$oldMessage}/", $deletedFormat, $str, 1);
```

Instead of

```
$str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);
```

Because: **str_replace** replaces everything.
**preg_replace** lets you limit how many replacements.